# IIS7 Application Configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I have a custom ASP.NET application that I utilize for several clients that I host.  Each client has a separate domain and the application is normally a child application under the root domain (http://domain.com/customapp).  The application files are the same (aspx, ascx, style sheets, images, etc.).  The only thing different is the web.config file for each client.  As development of the application continues to evolve, I have to update the application for each directory and this obviously becoming tedious.  I am trying to come up with a method keep the application up to date.  My first though is placing the application into a single physical path and creating multiple applications pointing to that path (the problem with this method is I can't have different web.config files).  I am curious as to what solution others are using in this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle this entirely in Visual Studio, [VS2010 offers web.config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx) which could solve your problem.

In a nutshell, create a build configuration (In VS, select Build|Configuration Manager...) for each site. Add a web.config transform for each client, which only specifies the differences required for each application.

I use this for differentiating between development, staging and release configurations - each transform adjusts the connection string, app settings, etc - and it works quite well both within Visual Studio and when deploying via MSBuild.

Also, note that **web.config settings are inherited** by IIS applications. So, if you have a root site

```
/root
```

and client apps

```
/root/client1
/root/client2
...
```

you could place the client-specific config settings in a web.config in each client-specific folder, and global settings a web.config in the root folder.

Comment: Thanks.  I am looking into this and testing it now.  Essentially the only client specific settings I am using as of now are a connection string and assemblyBinding\probing paths.  The problem is with inherited settings and I have to clear the connection string as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just move your web.config content to a database and load it conditionally based on the domain that was referenced?

```
    Select Case Request.Url.Host.ToLowerInvariant()
        Case "xyz.com", "www.xyz.com"
            'Load XYZ stuff'
        Case "abc.com", "www.abc.com"
            'Load ABC stuff'
        Case Else
            'Throw an error probably'
    End Select
```

Even better, store your domains in the database as keys so that you don't ever have to touch the code.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Any multi-tenant architecture is going to force you to put tenant specific information in the database.

Comment: @Chris depends on the type of tenant-specific information. Putting client-specific connection strings in the database presents something of a chicken/egg quandary.

Comment: That's possible.  Currently the client specific settings are connection string and probing paths in the assemblyBinding setting.

Comment: @Jason, so if the probing paths are different, does that mean that not _all_ files are the same then?

Comment: There's a plugin directory that is currently different which is a subdirectory of the application.  After consideration though I can use the same plugin directory, meaning all the files are the same, and store the settings in a database so this would ultimately remove the probing paths settings.  I wonder if there's a way to set the probing paths in the begin request of global.config?

Comment: Remember that assemblyBindings are application-level settings, not request-level. Once an application is loaded the bindings can't be changed until the next load. So when the first request comes in, say for client "a", they'll init the application which will then sit around until it times out. If client "b" comes in before that timeout the bindings will already be loaded still from client "a".